# What is the relationship between periodic boundary and the simulation box?

Tags: molecular-modeling, atomistic-simulation, periodic-boundary-conditions

Suppose, the size of my simulation box is:

- Width = 200
- Height = 100

Where,

- Top-left corner = (0, 0)
- Bottom-right corner = (200,100)
- Center of the coordinate is at (100, 50)

What would be the size of the periodic boundary?

Is that the same size as the dimensions of the simulation box, or is it different?

Comment: For the general solution (i.e. for triclinic shaped boxes) you might want to look at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20165/periodic-boundary-conditions-for-triclinic-box/20995#20995

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some pseudo-code

```
x_length = 200
y_length = 100

if x < 0: x += x_length
if x > x_length: x -= x_length
if y < 0: y += y_length
if y > y_length: y -= y_length
```

As you have alluded to, periodic boundary conditions adjust a coordinate by the size of the simulation box in that dimension.

I recommend [Understanding Molecular Simulation Algorithms by Frenkel & Smit](https://www.amazon.ca/Understanding-Molecular-Simulation-Algorithms-Applications/dp/0122673514) and [Computer Simulation of Liquids by Allen & Tildesley](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198803206). They are a rich source of simulation knowledge.

Comment: *Your units are a little funny since (0,0) is top left* --- This is how computer screens work. Isn't it?

Comment: I don't know, positive x values usually go to the right, positive y values usually go up, but in the end, it doesn't matter

Comment: *positive x values usually go to the right, positive y values usually go up* --- Not always. Especially if you are drawing on a Win32 GUI-based form.

Comment: @user366312 you may appreciate The Art of Molecular Dynamics Simulation by D.C. Rapaport. My impression is you have no issue coding, but are new to the application of molecular simulation. Rapaport has alot of really insightful code written in C. https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/art-of-molecular-dynamics-simulation/57D40C5ECE9B7EA17C0E77E7754F5874

Answer (score 0):

- Simulation box/cell: It is the box or the defined region with specified dimension that you build to study your system with specific number of molecules (based on density). Your system size should be large enough to avoid the finite size effect but small enough to avoid undue computation time.
- Periodic Boundary: In terms of dimension, as you asked it will be the same. But in technical sense, periodic boundary is a method which replicates your simulation cell into an infinite lattice.

Dimension will be the same of your simulation box size but two are different in technical meaning.

As @B.kelly answered, you could go through number of good reference books to understand the concept well (Computer Simulation of Liquids by Allen and Tidsley). This book is well known among those working with MD simulations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).